# I can not delete records from the database

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I can not delete records from the database.
In the page that I am creating, a user can delete the news that creates, when a user presses the button "delete", the system redirects to a file called "borrar_noticia.php". This archive take the variable utc by a "GET" and then makes the query to the database.

Here I leave the file showing news that makes a user:

```
    <?php
require('mysql.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE usuario ='".$_SESSION['usuario_t']."' ORDER BY utc DESC;");
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "
    <article>
        <div id='logov2b' style='background:url(\"photo/".$fila['icono'].".jpg\");'></div>
        <time>".$fila['ano']."-".$fila['mes']."-".$fila['dia']."</time>
        <h3>".$fila['titulo']."</h3>
        <h4>".$fila['subtitulo']."</h4>
        <p>".$fila['texto']."</p>
        <a href='includes/eliminar_post.php?id=".$fila['utc']."'>Eliminar</a> - Editar
    </article>
    ";
}
mysql_close($db_link);
?>
```

This is the file that queries the database:

```
<?php
require('mysql.php');

$id = $_GET['utc'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM post WHERE utc= '".$id."' LIMIT 1");
header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

This is the file that connecting the database:

```
<?php
$db_link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
if(!$db_link){
    die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('blog',$db_link);
if(!$db_selected){
    die('No se selecciono la BD: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Also, you should look into SQL Injection http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/ since what you are writing is screaming to be hacked.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to access to the `utc` key, but in the url you are using the `id` parameter. Try this in eliminar_post.php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.
This error was very simple, do not understand how I hadn't noticed
Topic Solved